# Can TFS track non-project tasks?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We have non-project tasks/issues and would like to centralize all work tracking to TFS (2008 and 2010 available).  Is there a clean way to track items that aren't linked to a project?  Thoughts and experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created a separate Team Project called "!WorkAndChangeRequests" (the exclamation point helps it get sorted to the top of the list).  There's no source control / builds associated with this projects.

One thing to keep in mind if you do this...  you will lose (some of) the ability to use the standard process-template reports.  Those reports are usually aligned towards an individual project.